# ASP Ajax Toolkit Calendar control defaults to mm/dd/yyyy can this be changed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I have a text box which has a Ajax calendar extender attached. You click on the text box, the calendar pops up, you select a date and that gets displayed in the text box. That all good but the date is displayed in mm/dd/yyyy format. Can this be changed?

Thanks,
Jonesy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set the "Format" attribute on the calendar extender to whatever format you want. Just use Format="MM/dd/yyyy" on the calendar extender attributes, (or whatever format you want) in order to set it.

You usualy do that in the html view of the form.